# Where can I modify detailed C# compiler optimization settings in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-optimization

In Visual Studio C/C++ projects, it's easy to modify compiler's optimization settings in "Property Pages | C/C++ | Optimization". For example, we may give different optimization levels such as /O2 and /O3, as well as advanced optimizations like "Omit Frame Pointers".

However, I can't simply find corresponding UIs in C# project of Visual Studio. All I can find is just turning off optimizations: the "Optimize code" check box is all I've got.

Can C# users control detailed compiler's optimizations like C/C++? Do I have to give compiler options in command line?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Much of the optimisation of C# code goes on at the JIT compiler level, rather than the C# compiler. Basically there are no such detailed settings as the ones available in C or C++.

There are a few performance-related elements of the runtime that can be tweaked, such as GC strategies, but not a great deal.

When I'm building benchmark tests etc from the command line I tend to just use something like this:

```
csc /o+ /debug- Test.cs
```

(I *believe* I have seen the presence of a matching pdb file make a difference to performance, possibly in terms of the cost of exceptions being thrown, hence the `debug-` switch... but I could be wrong.)

EDIT: If you want to see the difference each bit of optimization makes, there's one approach which could prove interesting:

- Compile the same code with and without optimization
- Use ildasm or Reflector in IL mode to see what the differences are
- Apply the same changes one at a time manually (using ilasm) and measure how much each one has

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I wanted to see performance differences w.r.t. compiler option settings for C# programs.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK C# compiler has no such detailed optimization properties. Probably optimization is either enabled or disabled.

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx

I found just two:

- `/filealign` Specifies the size of sections in the output file.
- `/optimize` Enables/disables optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

A bit OT, but someone looking at this question might find this useful:

Adding this to method signature:
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]

turns off compiler optimizations for that method.

See here for details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396