# Embed a string of compiler options in an executable (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, makefile

Using gcc and Makefiles, I am able to embed some compiler options into a string for an executable to access as follows:

Makefile:

```
CXX=/usr/bin/g++
CXXFLAGS=-ansi -Wall -c
CXXDEFINES='-DCXXCOMMAND="$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)"'
```

C++ file:

```
#ifdef CXXCOMMAND
    std::cout << "C++ Command: " << CXXCOMMAND << std::endl;
#endif
```

And then I am able to print it to the console from the executable.

Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio? Specifically I am looking to put in the optimization flags *(/O2, /Od, etc...)*, but the more I have access to, the better things will work for me.

*Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012*
*Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 SP1*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I modify detailed C# compiler optimization settings in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226157/where-can-i-modify-detailed-c-sharp-compiler-optimization-settings-in-visual-stu)

Comment: `cl` has a `/D` option that lets you define pre-processor macros; is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of. You can define a macro in the project properties that contains a string, and embed within it any project property values you want. However, these properties, while used to construct the command line, are not the actual command line flags themselves.

For example, add the following as a Preprocessor Definition in the C/C++ Preprocessor project properties:

```
CXXCOMMAND="%(Optimization)"
```

Then `CXXCOMMAND` is `"MinSpace"` for a build set to compile with /O1.

Just be careful to have only [an even number of quotes](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/419) in your preprocessor define...

Comment: To find out the name of each project property, simply set it to a non-default value and then look in the .vcxproj file using a text editor.